# span tag inside input group is not in a row, whats wrong with my styling (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have different long names in my span tag. The problem is that my input fields are not in a column. I want them to be among themselves (like the red line in the picture). Can u tell me what how to get the style i want.

[image: solution]

So this is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!--Site-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Site</span>
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Info"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!--Net -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Net</span>
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Info"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<!--Test-Nr. -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Test-Nr.</span>
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Info"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My questions:
How can i get them in one line?
how can i implement the same in bootstrap 4?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not set the same width for all of them?

Comment: Why do you use old bootstrap 3.4.1 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS, how to create a label width of the longest containing text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325426/css-how-to-create-a-label-width-of-the-longest-containing-text)

Comment: i dont know how to make the same in bootstrap 4 or 5 @SimoneRossaini

Comment: how can i do this @Geshode

Comment: no i am sorry :( @diegod

Comment: By setting `width` of `input-group-addon` within a css file.

Comment: .input-group-addon{
    width: 100px;
}
like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set min width of the grey box.

```
.input-group-addon {
    min-width:80px;
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075467/twitter-bootstrap-3-input-group-addon-not-all-the-same-size).

Working example:

```css
.input-group-addon {
  min-width: 80px;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!--Site-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Site</span>
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Info"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!--Net -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Net</span>
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Info"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<!--Test-Nr. -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Test-Nr.</span>
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Info"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">=</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```